# Secure SMS Sending API endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, sms, spam-prevention

## Explanation

I have an API running on [Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8) that uses [Nexmo Verify API](https://developer.nexmo.com/api/verify) in order to send a code by SMS for two things :

- **(1)** User account creation (check phone number before creating the
  account)
- **(2)** Forgotten password (check code sent before entering a new
  password)

This PHP API is used by an iOS Application and an Android Application.

In the first case **(1)**, I have to check that the phone number does not exist before sending a SMS.
In the second case **(2)**, I have to check that the phone number exists before sending a SMS.

So, I may have two API routes :

- One checks if a phone number already exists, so that the mobile applications can display the next page or display an error.
- The other one simply sends a sms code to a phone number.

## Problem

The problem is that we can have a route that looks like `/api/phone/sendcode` and anyone can call this route directly without using the mobile application if they find what the endpoint is (it's just an API after all). It can be easy to use this route to spam.
Or, they also could call a route `api/phone/exists` tons of time to try to get all existing users.

## Question

How can I secure the endpoints in order to avoid people using them directly to SPAM or to check in a loop if an account exists ?
I already have a throttling system to block a specific IP address to request an endpoint more that X times in a minute, but I think this is not enough and can be bypassed (using a proxy or whatever).

Also, I prefer to avoid using Captcha.

Comment: User based access + per user rate limits? You could always limit rate of sending to the same number too? Not 100% sure what the _actual_ question is.

Comment: At this point there is no user authenticated because the actual user is creating his account OR recovering his password. (no access_token yet)

Comment: You either need to sign the requests using some private key, or pass along an authentication token, which would get generated by server on a per-app basis. Using throttling + CAPTCHA might be a good compromise.

Comment: @Marc Have you solved this problem? I have the exact same problem and I am wondering if it is even possible to secure such endpoint in case when attackers use residential proxies for example